# Match exact values on oracle join

Tags: sql, oracle, join

Here it goes.
I have two tables say, Application and Report.
There tables have a common column(appId, externalAppId respectively) which can be joined to find unique values.
My problems is when I join these 2 tables, I'm getting values which I don't really want.

Sample values

```
Application   Report
No appId      ReportNo ExternalAppId
1  123         1        123
2  456         2        00000123
3  789         3        321
```

So when I say Application.appId = Report.ExternalAppId in my where condition, it is returning me rows of 123 and 00000123 from Report table . 
The leading zeros are not taken into account in the join.
 I need result with exact matches only.
 In this case, the first row alone.The cause of the issue I think is the appId is number and ExternalAppId is varchar.
 I cant change this also. Is there any workaround ?
 I have seen regex which can remove the leading zeros and then match, but just want to know if there is a better solution.
 ie can I specify that the join will work only for the values with exact match ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oracle can only compare two values of the **same datatype**. I can't stress this enough. In fact most languages can compare two values only if they are the same datatype. Relations in math will also be defined with objects of the same type (so that you can define [transitivity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_relation), [reflexivity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflexive_relation)...). There's also the saying with oranges and apples: don't try to compare them.

So when you ask Oracle to compare two values of different datatypes, an **implicit conversion** will take place. In most cases you should avoid these conversions, since the rules of which datatype will be chosen over the other can be quite complex and (like in this case) will often produce bugs because you will incorrectly guess which type will *win*. You should rely on explicit conversions (conversions that you specify).

I assume that `Application (appId)` is a `NUMBER` and `Report (ExternalAppId)` is of type `VARCHAR2`. In this case Oracle chose to convert `ExternalAppId` to a `NUMBER`, and in the `NUMBER` space, `00123=123` because **numbers have no format**.

You should have written instead your join condition as:

```
to_char(application.appId) = report.externalAppId
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. I knew something was wrong with the join. Thanks much !

Comment: But I still wonder why Oracle let the user to do that, instead of throwing a syntax error or something while running the query, like all the other programming languages.

Comment: @jijo You have to be aware of the datatype of your columns. Nothing is more important than the data in a database :) Also it might be an ANSI recommendation, since [Mysql behaves like that](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f0f7f/1), [SQLLite](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/f0f7f/1) also, and [SQL Server](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f0f7f/1) too. Only [PostgreSQL](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/f0f7f/1) raises an error.